# pt-online-schema-change with no changes

Tags: mysql, liquibase, percona

I have a table in MySQL that I need to rebuild for performance/storage reasons. Is it possible to use pt-online-schema-change with no changes for this purpose or is a change always required? If the former, can I specify this in Liquibase XML?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done this frequently to defragment and recover disk space on a table after a lot of updates or deletes. Any no-op alteration would work the same with pt-online-schema-change, but I use the option `--alter=FORCE` because it's mnemonic for `ALTER TABLE <name> FORCE` which would be a no-op table restructure if one were not using pt-online-schema-change.

I'm not familiar with Liquibase enough to know how to use it to run a pt-online-schema-change task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll likely use this since nobody has come back with a way that will work in Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB tables rarely need `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Big `DELETEs` should be performed in one of several more optimal ways.  Some other ways inherently lead to defragmenting as a side effect.

[*Big Deletes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

Comment: I'm actually setting some large BLOB columns to null and not deleting any rows. I'd be surprised if that space would be released without this.

Comment: @mjaggard - Large TEXT/BLOB columns are stored "off-record".  I do not know how well such space is reclaimed.  Do you have any before and after examples with `SHOW TABLE STATUS`?

Comment: I don't have examples right now but for one of my test databases before optimising the table was 130GB approx and after is around 50GB so I'm just asking how to do that in production. I'd much rather do it as part of our normal upgrade system which uses Liquibase but I'm fine with running manually if needed. I would likely be fine just running OPTIMIZE TABLE directly but there's a chance it could lock for too long and cause failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pt-online-schema-change` to rebuild tables. Use the below approach:

```
pt-online-schema-change --execute --alter "ENGINE=InnoDB;" D=<db_name>r,t=<table_name>
```